# From table to iGraph

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, igraph

I have organized my data as follow:

head(data1)
  n  V1  V2 Year  Influence        Dialogic

1 1 EXE MEC 1995 Coercitive      Antagonism

2 2 EXE MEC 1995 Coercitive      Antagonism

3 3 MEC CNE 1995 Coercitive Complementarity

4 4 MEC SES 1995 Coercitive Complementarity

5 5 MEC INE 1995 Coercitive Complementarity

6 6 MEC ALL 1995 Coercitive      Antagonism

...

Now, I am trying to figure out how to make V1 to V2, row by row, in igraph...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I got it!

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header= TRUE)
head(data)


data
a <- graph.data.frame(data, directed= FALSE)

par(mar= c(1, 1, 1, 1))
op<-(par(family="serif"))

plot(a, layout= layout.auto(a))
```